# Creating Guest Session

Tags: java, session, aem

Is there a way to create a guest session in AEM?

Our project will be an e-commerce website built on AEM and we need to track the session of the incoming guest and generate a token out of it, in case there will be saving of items on the cart. We need to track this guest session/token so just in case the user decides to log in to our site to checkout those items, the back-end services can map on the ownership of the cart based on the session/token.

Answer (score 0):

By default if a user is not logged in and content is viewed, AEM internally logs the user as "anonymous", you may consider this as guest.

You can get this value as below:

```
 import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable;
 import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager;
 import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
 import javax.jcr.Session;
 ...
 UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
 Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

 // Getting the current user                        
 Authorizable auth = userManager.getAuthorizable(session.getUserID());
 log.info("\n--- User, Principal="+auth.getID()+","+auth.getPrincipal().getName());

 // Do not try to get the token if no user logged in - anonymous
 if (auth.getID().equals(ANONYMOUS_USER)) {
     // Write your logic here        
 } else {
     // User logged
 }
```